# Trying to set icon on jlabel keeps breaking

Tags: java

Question I want to set an image from a file for a JLabel. How ever every time I run it I get this error below  --- Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated thank you!

## Here is my main class

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: horizontalAlignment
        at javax.swing.JLabel.checkHorizontalKey(JLabel.java:608)
        at javax.swing.JLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.java:766)
        at javax.swing.JLabel.<init>(JLabel.java:163)
        at javax.swing.JLabel.<init>(JLabel.java:183)
        at widget.Widget.<init>(Widget.java:30)
        at widget.Widget.main(Widget.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

```
public class Widget extends JFrame {
    static String temp;
    static String icon_image;

    public Widget(){
        setUndecorated(true);
        setSize(200,200);
        temp = weather.temp();
        icon_image = "C:\\Users\\jsnow\\IdeaProjects\\SnowWidget_x\\Images\\partlycloudy.gif";
                      //weather.weather_pic();

        JLabel myText = new JLabel("I: "+ temp,
                SwingConstants.TOP);

        JLabel mypic = new JLabel("h", SwingConstants.BOTTOM);

        mypic.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icon_image));

        add(myText);
        add(mypic);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        Shape shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0,0,200,200);
        AWTUtilities.setWindowShape(this, shape);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        new Widget();


    }

}
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong and where -- you're using the wrong 2nd parameter the horizontal alignment parameter for your JLabel constructor call. Read the [JLabel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel-javax.swing.Icon-int-) to see what's allowed.

Comment: Okay so how would I fix that? @HovercraftFullOfEels example please

Comment: You could only use horizontal alignments with JLabel. But here you have used vertical alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change both places you call to `new` JLabel to something like this:

```
    JLabel mypic = new JLabel("h", JLabel.CENTER);
```